# Java Checking name against file

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment.  For this assignment, I need take two names and check that name against a file with a list of names. The names are in the first column. I have a string set up to pass the first question to it create a string within the method that separates the name if it is in the file. What I wanted to do was create a loop so that it will loop, ask the question repeatedly, until it verifies the name is in it with the first one then create a string following it doing the same. My problem arises in that, it seems to be stuck in an endless loop. I was hoping someone can point me in the right direction?

Here is the runnable example to duplicate the problem.

File.txt (This is a partial, but works just the same):

> Abbie 431 552 742 924 0 0 0 0 752 644 601
>   Abbigail 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 953 562
>   Abby 0 0 0 0 0 906 782 548 233 211 209
>   Abdiel 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 925 721
>   Abdul 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 903 0 0 0
>   Abdullah 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 863
>   Abe 248 328 532 764 733 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   Abel 664 613 626 575 542 491 497 422 381 385 354

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program52 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String firstName = getName("First name: ");
        String secondName = getName("Second name: ");
    }

    public static String getName(String getUserName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        String name = "";
        boolean nameVerified = false;

        while (nameVerified == false) {
            File fileNames = new File("/file.txt");
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(fileNames);

            System.out.print(getUserName);
            String name1 = in.next();
            String name2 = in.next();

            while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {

                String line = scnr.nextLine();
                if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith(name1.toLowerCase())) {
                    count++;
                    if (count == 1) {
                        nameVerified = true;
                        System.out.println();
                        name = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(" "));

                        System.out.println(name);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (nameVerified == false) {
                System.out.print("Invalid. Enter another name: ");
                name1 = in.next();
                name2 = in.next();
            }
        }
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should have line.toLowerCase().startsWith(name1.toLowerCase()) or name2. It is not clear why you have name1 and name2. Is that for name and surname?

Comment: Oh, sorry for not being clear.  There will be two string calls to that method:
  String firstName = getName("First name: ");
 
  String secondName = getName("Second name: ");
That's why there's name1 and name2.
And I changed that, thanks a lot!  I can't believe I missed that.  But unfortunately, it's still stuck in the loop endlessly.  Any other ideas?  Thanks again.

Comment: Your scanners should be closed when you're done with them. Simply wrap them in `try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(...)) {...}` to auto-close them after leaving the `try` block. Another issue: maybe you should read your file only once and store the names in memory to use them inside your while-loop. Last point: you're comparing `getUserName` instead of `name1` with the file contents.

Comment: For this assignment, unfortunately, I am not allowed to use try and catch.  I'm basically limited to what's up there(any loops, strings, scanners, but that's about it).  I did put the file in the first while loop, thanks a lot!  But, unfortunately, that still didn't solve the problem.  Any other ideas?  Thanks a lot again!

Comment: As a verification, try printing out the line you read in from file.txt as well as the names you read in from the System.in right when you receive them.  This is just to verify you are getting the contents you are expecting.

Comment: I just tried that in my main method, before it initializes the first string and it worked fine just using a simple while loop with a print statement "    while(scnr.hasNextLine()){
     
     String line = scnr.nextLine();
     System.out.println(line);
    }"
I did it in the method I was calling before it asks the question and it worked just fine again, but then when I throw it into the while loop where I want the work to be done, nothing is printed out.  Have any ideas, by chance?

Comment: For better help sooner please post a [Runnable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and a sample file, so we can copy-paste it and see the same issue than you

Comment: Sorry about the scnr, I fixed that.  I accidentally copied it improperly.

Comment: Ok, next question: what is the file content and what do you enter into the console?

Comment: I just uploaded a runnable example with partial contents of the list.
At this time, what I am trying to do is take a name and make sure it's in that list, if it's not then force them to pick a name that's on the list(The original file is much, much larger).  And upon getting a proper name, save the string in the main method to that so I can manipulate it differently.  Once I get this part solved, though, the rest should be easy enough.

Comment: I repeat a part of my old comment: *"and what do you enter into the console"*. Please answer this. Btw your code works fine.

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone!  I figured out what my problem was.  I had to get rid of the name2 entirely.  Thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: Please don't edit your question, add an answer instead :) with the current solution you got :D

Comment: So you really forgot to enter something for `name2`? Mhh ... :P

Comment: Btw: like @Frakcool wrote, don't add a solution of your question into your question. You should have added an answer instead. I created on for you, which contains your fixed code.

Comment: @Frakcool Sorry, but I had to rollback OPs last edit. That's why your suggested edit was rejected (automatically). Since you earn the (unreviewed) edit privilege soon, please mind that the recommended behaviour is to rollback the last edit and to create a community wiki with OPs answer. But I guess you already know that, because you told OP what he should do. Thank you.

Comment: @Tom don't worry :) I'm missing 2 more points to have the roll back, I can't by now but that was my original idea... Thank you anyway, I doubted in posting the wiki answer :P

Comment: @Frakcool Well, that's the irony: if your edit were approved, you would have that privilege :D.

Comment: I will remember this in the future.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Tom now I can (too late tho). Again thanks for the suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP solved this problem by removing the `name2` variable and the requested second user input.

Here is his fix code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program52 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String firstName = getName("First name: ");
        String secondName = getName("Second name: ");
    }

    public static String getName(String getUserName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        String name = "";
        boolean nameVerified = false;

        while (nameVerified == false) {
            File fileNames = new File("/file.txt");
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(fileNames);

            System.out.print(getUserName);
            String name1 = in.next();

            while (scnr.hasNextLine()) {

                String line = scnr.nextLine();
                if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith(name1.toLowerCase())) {
                    count++;
                    if (count == 1) {
                        nameVerified = true;
                        System.out.println();
                        name = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(" "));

                        System.out.println(name);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (nameVerified == false) {
                System.out.print("Invalid name.");
            }
        }
        return name;
    }
}
```